Tkinter with function on_click(event)
I make tic-tac-toe graphics for the project. when there are more than 3 tic-tac-toe marks on the field, the initial one disappears. The problem is that the winning combinations are broken. Combinations do not work diagonally, on the sides. Please help, because I am not particularly eager to spend a couple more hours at this job. Thank you in advance
from tkinter import *

frm= []; btn = []; who = True
playArea = []
standings = []                   # Турнирная таблица (приложение)
moves = []
array = []


def play(n):
    global who
    btn[n].config(text= 'X' if who else '0', state=DISABLED)
    playArea[n] = 1 if who else -1
    standings[0] = playArea[0] + playArea[1] + playArea[2]
    standings[1] = playArea [3] + playArea[4] + playArea[5]
    standings[2] = playArea [6] + playArea[7] + playArea[8]
    standings[3] = playArea[0] + playArea[3] + playArea[6]
    standings[4] = playArea [1] + playArea[4] + playArea[7]
    standings [5] = playArea [2] + playArea [5] + playArea[8]
    standings[6] = playArea[0] + playArea [4] + playArea[8]
    standings [7] = playArea [2] + playArea[4] + playArea[6]
    print(playArea,n, standings [0:8])

    for i in range(3):
        if standings[i] == 3:
           root = Tk()
           root.title('Player X Won!')
           lbl1 = Label(root, text='Player X has won! Congrats!')
           lbl1.grid(column=0, row=0)
           root.geometry('350x175')
           lbl1.place(x=110, y=70)
           root.mainloop()
        elif standings[i] == -3:
           root = Tk()
           root.title('Player 0 Won!')
           lbl1 = Label(root, text='Player 0 has won! Congrats!')
           lbl1.grid(column=0, row=0)
           root.geometry('350x175')
           lbl1.place(x=110, y=70)
           root.mainloop()
    who = not(who)

    def on_click(event):
        print(f"Clicked at x={standings}")

    moves = (n)
    array.append(n)
    g = (array[0])
    desired_length = 5

    def check_array_length(array, desired_length):
        if len(array) > desired_length:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    if check_array_length(array, desired_length):
        btn[g].config(text='', state=NORMAL)
        array.pop(0)
        playArea[g] = 0

for i in range(3):
    frm.append(Frame())
    frm[i].pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
    for j in range(3):
        btn.append(Button(frm[i], text=' ', font=('mono', 20, 'bold'), width=3, height=2))
        btn[i*3+j].config(command=lambda n=i*3+j:play(n))
        btn[i*3+j].pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT, padx=1, pady=1)
        playArea.append(0)
        standings.append(0)
mainloop()


You need to go through the eight values in standings to check for winner, but now you just go through the first three values.

What line? Can you say pls

for i in range(3) inside play().

but with it isnt work other functions(on_click, check_array_length and if check_array_length)

One question one issue. And I don't understand what these function are for.

maybe code would be simpler if you would keep board as 2D list (nested list) and use playArea[row][col]. it could be also more readable if you would use names row, col instead of i,j

tkinter should run only one mainloop(), If you want to redraw window before end of your function then use root.update() instead of root.mainloop() . And if you want to stop checking other values in loop then use return to exit function. And if you want to display another window then you should rather use Toplevel() instead of Tk() to create next  windows.

as @acw1668 already said you use for i in range(3) to check standing[i] == 3 so you check only 3 items instead of 9 items. But you wouldn't have this problem if you would use for item in standing: (and check if item == 3) - without using indexes.

BTW: Using .grid(row=..., column=...) instead of .pack() you could run it without Frame

I didn't test it but you have wrong value in range() in
(and @acw1668 already said it in comment)
for i in range(3):
    if standings[i] == 3:
        # ... code ...
    if standings[i] == -3:
        # ... code ...

because it checks only 3 items (3 horizontal)
instead of 8 items (3 horizontal + 3 vertical + 2 diagonal).
You should use range(8) or even better you could iterate standing
for item in standing:
    if item == 3:
        # ... code ...
    if item == -3:
        # ... code ...


EDIT:
Full working code with other changes.
PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code
Because words button and buttons are very similar (and this can make mistakes)
so I use all_buttons to make bigger difference.
But it is not suggested but PEP8.

EDIT:
(as @acw1668 pointed out in a comment) I add who = True in reset_game() and I remove standings from global variables because standings is used only inside play()
import tkinter as tk   # PEP8: `import *` us not preferred

# --- constants ---  # PEP8: constants before classes

# --- classes ---    # PEP8: classes before functions

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: functions before main code

def winner_window(name):
    subwindow = tk.Toplevel()

    subwindow.title(f'Player {name} Won!')
    
    label = tk.Label(subwindow, text=f'Player {name} has won!\n\nCongrats!')
    label.pack(padx=100, pady=50)

    button = tk.Button(subwindow, text='Play Again', command=subwindow.destroy)
    button.pack(fill='both', ipady=10)
    
    #subwindow.mainloop()


def reset_game():
    global play_area
    global who

    for button in all_buttons:
        button.config(text=' ', state='normal')
    
    play_area = [0] * 9
    who = True


def play(number):
    global who
    
    button = all_buttons[number]
    
    button.config(text= 'X' if who else '0', state='disabled')
    play_area[number] = 1 if who else -1
    
    standings = [
        # horizontal
        play_area[0] + play_area[1] + play_area[2],
        play_area[3] + play_area[4] + play_area[5],
        play_area[6] + play_area[7] + play_area[8],
        # vertical
        play_area[0] + play_area[3] + play_area[6],
        play_area[1] + play_area[4] + play_area[7],
        play_area[2] + play_area[5] + play_area[8],
        # diagonal
        play_area[0] + play_area[4] + play_area[8],
        play_area[2] + play_area[4] + play_area[6],
    ]

    for item in standings:
        if item == 3:
            winner_window('X')
            reset_game()
            return
        elif item == -3:
            winner_window('0')
            reset_game()
            return

    who = not who

# --- main code ---

# PEP8: don't put all in one line - it is unreadable 
all_buttons = []     # PEP8: more readable names for variables
who = True           
play_area = [0] * 9  # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables

root = tk.Tk()

for row in range(3):
    for col in range(3):
        number = (row * 3) + col

        button = tk.Button(root, text=' ', font=('mono', 20, 'bold'), width=3, height=2, command=lambda n=number:play(n))
        button.grid(row=row, column=col, padx=1, pady=1)
        all_buttons.append(button)

#reset_game()  # set all values even before first game

root.mainloop()


Your code is working.

standings is not necessary to be a global variable.  Also who should be reset inside reset_game().

@acw1668 you are right. Now I see standings is used only in play. And who should be reset too. I added it in answer. Thanks.

You forgot to initialize standings inside play() before assigning values to it.

@acw1668 you are right again. I was rather thinking about creating directly all values on the list standings = [ .... ] but I forgot to change it :)
